# style.transformStyle property doesn't work in JavaScript, only in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

Frankly I don't have much commentary beyond "I don't know why it doesn't work". I read somewhere that this feature is really buggy and sometimes doesn't work in "deeply nested" bits of code. For reference, this is a snippet of where it is working:

```css
#page {
  perspective: 600px;
  perspective-origin: 0% 0%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

* {
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#a,
#b {
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRSebrZe4wwOqHYjD6ohuiHUc_Hf4VlViIkqTphL5GD&s');
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#a {
  transform: translate3d(100px, 50px, 0px) rotatey(90deg);
}

#b {
  transform: translate3d(100px, 100px, 0px) rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="page">fasd
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

But whenever I try to do it in JavaScript it doesn't work. here's the code I need to fix:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>city</title>
    <style>
      @keyframes radical {
        0% {transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 0deg);}
      100% {transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 360deg);}
      }

      @keyframes perspec {
        0% {perspective:    500px;}
        50% {perspective: 260px;}
        100% {perspective: 500px;}
      }

      @keyframes perspec2 {
        0% {transform: rotateX(2deg);}
        50% {transform: rotateX(-13deg);}
        100% {transform: rotateX(2deg);}
      }

      @keyframes scroll {
        0% {background-position: 0px 0px;}
        100% {background-position: 400px 0px;}
      }

      @keyframes rotate {
        0% {transform: rotateZ(10deg);}
        100% {transform: rotateZ(-10deg);}
      }

      body {background-color: green;}
      body * {
        position: absolute;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
      }

      #page {
        width: 97%;
        height: 90%;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        left: 2%;
        top: 15px;
        perspective: 200px;
        animation: rotate 0s linear alternate-reverse infinite;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
            perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
        overflow: scroll !important;
        transform-style:preserve-3d;
      }

      #extreme {
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 100;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
        animation: radical 4s linear infinite;
        transform-style: flat;
      }

      .door {
        background-image: url('images/foreground/door.png');
        background-size: 100% 100%;
      }
      
      * {
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
      }

    </style>
    <script>
      function doorone() {
        window.location.href = "beach.html";
      }

      function doortwo() {
        window.location.href = "placeholder.html";
      }

      function doorthree() {
        window.location.href = "placeholder.html";
      }
      
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      buildingGenerator()
      }, false); //i could just do onload but i thought this was cooler
   
   
      var howfarbackeverythingis = -200
      
      function buildingGenerator() {
        divFactory(120, 52, 200, 300, 175)
        divFactory(200, 380, 120, 700, 250)

        divFactory(140, 70, 240, 400, 405)
        divFactory(340, 160, 240, 800, 505)
        divFactory(1000, 60, 300, 500, 800)
      }
      
        //untesting!!
      function divFactory(sizex, sizey, height, offsetx, offsety) {
        const ceiling = document.createElement("div");
        const topwall = document.createElement("div");
        const leftwall = document.createElement("div");
        const rightwall = document.createElement("div");
        const bottomwall = document.createElement("div");
        const floor = document.createElement("div");
        const page = document.getElementById("page")
        
        ceiling.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        ceiling.style.position = "absolute"
        ceiling.style.transformStyle = "preserve-3d";
        ceiling.style.width = sizex+"px";
        ceiling.style.height = sizey+"px";
        ceiling.style.transform = "translate3d("+ (offsetx) +"px, "+ (offsety) +"px, "+ (howfarbackeverythingis + height) +"px) rotatex(0deg)"
        
        topwall.style.backgroundColor = "red"; //backup
        topwall.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/foreground/bricks.png')";
        topwall.style.position = "absolute"
        topwall.style.transformOrigin = "top";
        topwall.style.transformStyle = "preserve-3d";
        topwall.style.width = sizex+"px";
        topwall.style.height = height+"px";
        topwall.style.transform = "translate3d("+ (offsetx) +"px, "+ (offsety) +"px, "+ (howfarbackeverythingis) +"px) rotatex(90deg)"
        leftwall.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/foreground/bricks.png')";

        leftwall.style.backgroundColor = "darkblue"; //backup
        leftwall.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/foreground/bricks.png')";
        leftwall.style.position = "absolute"
        leftwall.style.transformOrigin = "top";
        leftwall.style.transformStyle = "preserve-3d";
        leftwall.style.width = sizey+"px";
        leftwall.style.height = height+"px";
        leftwall.style.transform = "translate3d("+ (offsetx - sizey / 2) +"px, "+ (offsety + sizey / 2) +"px, "+ (howfarbackeverythingis) +"px) rotatex(90deg) rotatey(90deg)"
        
        rightwall.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue"; //backup
        rightwall.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/foreground/bricks.png')";
        rightwall.style.position = "absolute"
        rightwall.style.transformOrigin = "top";
        rightwall.style.transformStyle = "preserve-3d";
        rightwall.style.width = sizey+"px";
        rightwall.style.height = height+"px";
        rightwall.style.transform = "translate3d("+ ((offsetx - sizey / 2)+ sizex) +"px, "+ (offsety + sizey / 2) +"px, "+ (howfarbackeverythingis) +"px) rotatex(90deg) rotatey(90deg)"
        
        bottomwall.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; //backup
        bottomwall.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/foreground/bricks.png')";
        bottomwall.style.transformOrigin = "top";
        bottomwall.style.transformStyle = "preserve-3d";
        bottomwall.style.width = sizex+"px";
        bottomwall.style.height = height+"px";
        bottomwall.style.transform = "translate3d("+ (offsetx) +"px, "+ (offsety + sizey) +"px, "+ (howfarbackeverythingis) +"px) rotatex(90deg) rotatey(0deg)"
        console.log(sizey)
        console.log(offsetx)
        console.log("---")
        page.appendChild(ceiling);
            page.appendChild(topwall);
            page.appendChild(leftwall);
            page.appendChild(rightwall);
            page.appendChild(bottomwall);
      }
     
      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="extreme">city</p>
    <div id="page">
      <div class="door" id="doorone" onclick="doorone()"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

this is NOT a duplicate because this is for dynamically created elements.

edit: sorry for lack of clarification, i meant how in the first snippet the two divs intersect and clip like they would in like a regular 3D projection, which is what TransformStyle should do, but in the second code snippet none of the divs created in javascript that make up the 'buildings' intersect/clip, and look like they're on different layers as if they had different z-indexes

Comment: What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported? When you inspect the added elements in the browser, do you see the styles applied to the elements?

Comment: The two examples are very different. It's not clear what exactly is "working" in the first snippet that is not in the second. When I run the second code snippet here, in Chrome 116.0.5845.188 on Windows 10, it seems to generate "buildings"...

Comment: sorry about that, i meant how in the first one the two divs intersect and clip like they would in like blender or really any 3D projection, which is what  TransformStyle should do, but in the second code snippet none of the divs that make up the buildings intersect correctly, and seem to be on different 'layers' as if they had differing z-indexes.

Comment: Well all the elements show up in the browser with the local style properties set in a way that seems consistent with the JavaScript code. You know what it's supposed to look like but we don't.

Comment: And your edit un-did the snippet work done a little while ago.